# TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable while converting to parquet file

Tags: json, python-3.x, typeerror, parquet

I have a data frame which looks something like this

[image]

I am trying the data to be in parquet file using

```
df4.to_parquet('df4.parquet.gzip',compression='gzip')
```

and getting `TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable`

the column data types are

```
3
MANDT    object
QMNUM    object
QMART    object
QMTXT    object
ARTPR    object
PRIOK    object
ERNAM    object
ERDAT    object
AENAM    object
AEDAT    object
MZEIT    object
QMDAT    object
QMNAM    object
STRMN    object
STRUR    object
LTRMN    object
LTRUR    object
WAERS    object
AUFNR    object
VERID    object
dtype: object
```

Where `3` is the index name

Comment: Same problem. identical, anyone got it solved?